# Loading hyperspectral images in Octave

Tags: image, matlab, octave

Using Matlab I can see the 4th channel of my image, but not with Octave:

the following Matlab code for image (I) gives

> I =imread('../rec3/2012R_1_1.tif') [nr nc nb] = size(I);
>   nb

It gives out :

> nb =  4

where `nb` is the channel number and `I` is a 64 bit image(3057x1210)

But for the same image Octave gives :

> nb = 3

Should I load any special package in order to be able to work with hyperspectral images?

**EDIT**

**The output of the imfinfo for Octave:**

ans =

scalar structure containing the fields:

```
Filename = c:/2012R_1_1.tif
FileModDate = 10-May-2016 20:02:10
FileSize =  23140500
Format = TIFF
FormatVersion =
Width =  3057
Height =  1210
BitDepth =  16
ColorType = truecolor
DelayTime = 0
DisposalMethod =
LoopCount = 0
ByteOrder = undefined
Gamma = 0
Chromaticities = [](1x0)
Comment =
Quality =  75
Compression = undefined
Colormap = [](0x0)
Orientation =  1
ResolutionUnit = Inch
XResolution = 0
YResolution = 0
Software =
Make =
Model =
DateTime =
ImageDescription =
Artist =
Copyright =
```

**and for Matlab**

```
Filename: 'c:\2012R_...'
              FileModDate: '10-máj.-2016 18:02:10'
                 FileSize: 23140500
                   Format: 'tif'
            FormatVersion: []
                    Width: 3057
                   Height: 1210
                 BitDepth: 64
                ColorType: 'truecolor'
          FormatSignature: [73 73 42 0]
                ByteOrder: 'little-endian'
           NewSubFileType: 0
            BitsPerSample: [16 16 16 16]
              Compression: 'LZW'
PhotometricInterpretation: 'RGB'
             StripOffsets: [1x38 double]
          SamplesPerPixel: 4
             RowsPerStrip: 32
          StripByteCounts: [1x38 double]
              XResolution: []
              YResolution: []
           ResolutionUnit: 'Inch'
                 Colormap: []
      PlanarConfiguration: 'Chunky'
                TileWidth: []
               TileLength: []
              TileOffsets: []
           TileByteCounts: []
              Orientation: 1
                FillOrder: 1
         GrayResponseUnit: 0.0100
           MaxSampleValue: [65535 65535 65535 65535]
           MinSampleValue: [0 0 0 0]
             Thresholding: 1
                   Offset: 23139726
                Predictor: 'Horizontal differencing'
             ExtraSamples: 0
             SampleFormat: {'Unsigned integer'  'Unsigned integer'  'Unsigned integer'  'Unsigned integer'}
       ModelPixelScaleTag: [1 1 1]
         ModelTiepointTag: [0 0 0 6.7143e+05 5.1757e+06 0]
       GeoKeyDirectoryTag: [1x52 double]
       GeoDoubleParamsTag: []
        GeoAsciiParamsTag: ''
```

Comment: could you please provide an example image?

Comment: Show the code also.

Comment: Hi, I just use:  I =imread('../rec3/2012R_1_1.tif'); then the above shown lines

Comment: Sorry I am not allowed to upload the image :(

Comment: You do realize that, without an example of the image (even mock data which behave the same on your setup), it is way harder to come up for a solution for your specific problem ?

Comment: what does `imfinfo` output in each environment?

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Please, find the imfinfo for the two environment.

Comment: If I write a (5,5,4) array as a tif image and read it back, I get imfinfo headers like yours, and octave reads the image in with the right size. Is that the case with you too? Otherwise, perhaps it's a special format? Try to `imwrite` the image data as a tif file in matlab and read it back into octave and see if that helps. Also, maybe your octave version is just old?

Comment: As others already said, upload a image so we can test. You should also mention the used GNU Octave version. From the image path I guess you are on windoze but you should also mention this in your question

Answer (score 2):

You can use the functions [rasterread](https://octave.sourceforge.io/mapping/function/rasterread.html) or [gdalread](https://octave.sourceforge.io/mapping/function/gdalread.html) from the `mapping` package to read hyperspectral images.

```
pkg load mapping
ras = rasterread("myfile.tif");
I = ras.data;
```

or

```
[~,~,I]= gdalread("myfile.tif");
```